# IF-statement applied to substring of a string in a specific position

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working with a bunch of `*.tif` files which are named like: `[20120101.tif, 20120102.tif, 20120103.tif, ...]` (i.e. `YEARMONTHDAY.tif`). The issue is that I have to work only with the files corresponding to some specific months (e.g. JAN, FEB, MAR, NOV, DEC). I was planning to use `IF` statement but I am not sure how to apply it in order to work only for some months. Bellow, I show my code.

```
Root_dir = r"f:\myTifFiles"
os.chdir(Root_dir)
List_tif = glob.glob("*.tif")

for i in range(len(List_tif)):
    if ... #in this line I was planning to call a conditional statement to work only with some specific months
        Raster = gdal.Open(List_tif[i])
        geotransform = Raster.GetGeoTransform()
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: first of all  use `for item in iterable:`, second of, just do sth like `if month in ("jan", "feb")` and so on, maybe you will need to parse that number too, but also can just use sth like `if item[4:5+1] in ("01", "02", "11"):`...

Comment: You can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime(filename, '%Y%m%d').date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the filename into a `datetime.date` object, which you can then query for its `month` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List_tif = glob.glob("*.tif")
months_to_process = ['01','02','11']  # months you have to work with.

for image in List_tif:
    # extract a substring at index 4,5 example: 20220123.tif ==> 01
    # then check if the extracted value is in the months you need to process.
    # Then you can do what you need
    if image[4:6] in months_to_process:
        Raster = gdal.Open(List_tif[i])
        geotransform = Raster.GetGeoTransform()
```